# Find the area between the graphs of $f(x)=e^{.25x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ between $x=1$ and $x=2$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

5.5

Can somebody verify this solution for me?

Find the area between the graphs of $f(x)=e^{.25x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ between $x=1$ and $x=2$

Since $f(x) > g(x)$ on $(1,2)$, the area between the graphs is:

$\int_1^2 e^{.25x} - (\frac{-1}{x})dx$

$=\int_1^2 e^{.25x} + (\frac{1}{x})dx$

$= \frac{e^{.25x}}{.25} + ln(|x|)|_1^2dx$

$= \frac{e^{.25(2)}}{.25} + ln(2) - \frac{e^{.25(1)}}{.25} - ln(1)$

$= \frac{e^{.25(2)}}{.25} + ln(2) - \frac{e^{.25(1)}}{.25} - ln(1)$

Since $ln(1)=0$, we get:

$= 4e^{.5} + ln(2) - 4e^{.25}$

Comment: Looks right.  You wrote that the limits of integration were $0$ and $1$, whereas they are $1$ and $2$, btw.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Right on point. +1

Comment: Instead of $+\ln(1)$, you mean $-\ln(1)$. Of course it makes no difference, since both are zero.

Comment: @ MSV You seem to be verifying a lot of integration problems on Maths Stackechange. And you also seem to be getting most of the questions right which shows integration isn't really that hard for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, area is an absolute thing. So we know that the total area $\mathcal{A}$ is given by:

$$\mathcal{A}=\int_1^2\exp\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\space\text{d}x+\left|\int_1^2-\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x\right|=$$
$$\left[4\exp\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\right]_1^2+\left|\left[-\ln\left|x\right|\right]_1^2\right|=$$
$$4\exp\left(\frac{2}{4}\right)-4\exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left|-\ln\left|2\right|-\left(-\ln\left|1\right|\right)\right|=$$
$$4\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-4\exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left|-\ln\left|2\right|-\left(-0\right)\right|=$$
$$4\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-4\exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left|-\ln\left|2\right|\right|=$$
$$4\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-4\exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\ln\left(2\right)\approx2.15193\tag1$$

> So, yes you're right.